# How to write a one line command line that checks for internet downtime?

Tags: bash, command-line

I want to write a one line command line that

1. Pings google.com non stop
2. When the ping timesout (lost
   connection), echo an error message on screen

Comment: Hi and welcome to U&L. 1. Why does it need to be a one-line command? That seems a little arbitrary. 2. I don't think your proposed method would work, because it wouldn't be able to differentiate between your internet going down and that specific site having downtime.

Comment: it's ok to assume that google will always be up. I want to run it from just the command prompt, dont really want to run a script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `curl` or `ping` but I'm not sure why do you want to do this.

```
while curl -Lsf google.com >/dev/null || { printf 'Lost connection!' >&2; break; }; do :; done
```

```
while ping -c 1 google.com >/dev/null || { printf 'Lost connection!' >&2; break; }; do :; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner for bash or similar shells:

```
HOST=google.com; while true; do if ping -c 2 $HOST >/dev/null; then :; else echo "$(date) cannot reach $HOST"; fi; sleep 10; done
```